# AsyncTask doInBackground method - parameter error

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using an AsyncTask to call some code in another class:

```
public class addNewLocation extends AsyncTask<HomerLocation, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(HomerLocation... location) {
        bridge.addNewLocation(location);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        System.out.println("Result after execution is : " + result);
    }
}
```

I'm calling this via this command in a buttons code:

```
new addNewLocation().execute(newLocation,null,null);
```

newLocation being an Object with a few attributes which I set via user's input in a dialog.

The line "bridge.addNewLocation(location); is trying to call the addNewLocation method in my bridge class passing a HomerLocation object called location as a parameter. However, I'm getting an error:

```
The method addNewLocation(HomerLocation) in the type HomerJSONBridge is not 
applicable for the arguments (HomerLocation[])
```

The bridge class's method is as follows:

```
public void addNewLocation(HomerLocation location) {
    // code to add new location to homer
    //HomerLocation location = locationArray;
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(HomerURL);
    url.append("%7B%22operation%22%3A%22setLocation%22%2C%20%22name%22%3A%22"+location.getName()+
            "%22%2C%20%22locationContextID%22%3A%22"+location.getContextID()+"%22%2C%20%22image%22%3A%22"+location.getIcon()+
            "%22%2C%22design%22%3A%22"+location.getDesign()+"%22%7D");
}
```

This passes a JSON command to the servlet I'm accessing. If I rewrite the code in all places as follows:

```
protected Void doInBackground(HomerLocation... location) {
        HomerLocation location1 = location[0];
        bridge.addNewLocation(location1);
        return null;
    }
```

and

```
 public void addNewLocation(HomerLocation[] locationArray) {
    // code to add new location to homer
    HomerLocation location = locationArray[0];
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(HomerURL);
    url.append("%7B%22operation%22%3A%22setLocation%22%2C%20%22name%22%3A%22"+location.getName()+
            "%22%2C%20%22locationContextID%22%3A%22"+location.getContextID()+"%22%2C%20%22image%22%3A%22"+location.getIcon()+
            "%22%2C%22design%22%3A%22"+location.getDesign()+"%22%7D");
}
```

I still get a similar error (!) :

```
The method addNewLocation(HomerLocation[]) in the type HomerJSONBridge is 
not applicable for the arguments (HomerLocation)
```

I'm really confused as it seems to be both a HomerLocation object and also a HomerLocation[]! Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected Void doInBackground(HomerLocation... location)
```

The `...` syntax in method parameters means `location` is an array of `HomerLocation` (`HomerLocation[]`), not a single `HomerLocation` object.

If you're sure it's always gonna be one element wide, then quickest fix is:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(HomerLocation... location) {
    bridge.addNewLocation(location[0]);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this Because your HomerLocation... location is and array of HomerLocation objects.

```
protected Void doInBackground(HomerLocation... location) {

    bridge.addNewLocation(location[0]);
    return null;
}
```

and

```
public void addNewLocation(HomerLocation locationArray) {

   HomerLocation location = locationArray;
   client = new DefaultHttpClient();
   StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(HomerURL);
   url.append("%7B%22operation%22%3A%22setLocation%22%2C%20%22name%22%3A%22"+location.getName()+
        "%22%2C%20%22locationContextID%22%3A%22"+location.getContextID()+"%22%2C%20%22image%22%3A%22"+location.getIcon()+
        "%22%2C%22design%22%3A%22"+location.getDesign()+"%22%7D");
}
```

I think this will help you.